# При установке больше 2 alarms "приходит" только последний

Tags: android, java

Я пытаюсь устанавливать больше двух будильников alarms и присылать уведомления, но при приходит почему-то только последний установленный, хотя оба удачно пишутся в БД и ставятся в систему. Вот фрагмент Сервиса, который устанавливает Alarms:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time, diff;
        do {
            i = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            i.putExtra(AlarmMsg.COL_ID, c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(AlarmMsg.COL_ID)));
            i.putExtra(AlarmMsg.COL_ALARMID, c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(AlarmMsg.COL_ALARMID)));

            pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, requestCode, intent, flags);

            time = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(AlarmMsg.COL_DATETIME));
            diff = time-now + (long)Util.MIN;
            if (CREATE.equals(action)) {
                if (diff > 0 && diff < Util.YEAR)
                    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pi);
                Log.d("myTag","Service: setAlarm");
                //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, interval, operation);

            } else if (CANCEL.equals(action)) {
                am.cancel(pi);
            }
        } while(c.moveToNext());
```

Comment: Ну... Э-э-э... Может, при каждой итерации создавать новый экземпляр am?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот секунду назад разобрался - и заработало: нужно в итерации менять `requestCode` каждого создаваемого `pendingIntent` и добавлять его в `List<PendindIntent`>, потом в классе, который отправляет уведомления, в итерации на каждый итем массива создавать уведомление.